# Prove that this function is limited from the down side and not from the upper side.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

$y=\frac{12}{x} \quad \text{and} \quad x >0  
 $Well it shows a part of a hyperbole and $x$ shouldn't be $0$.But how can I prove that is is limited from the down side?
EDIT: Please no limits

Comment: $$x>0 \rightarrow \frac{1}{x}>0\\$$multiply by 12$$12\frac{1}{x}>12(0)\\\frac{12}{x}>0$$so $$ 0<\frac{12}{x} <\infty $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not limited from the upper side, because, by absurd, if there was a $M>0$ that verify $\forall x, \frac{12}{x} < M$, you could take $x= \frac{1}{M} >0$ and this inequality become $12 < 1$, wich is false.

It's bounded from the down side because 12/x is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{12}{x}=+\infty $$
therefore it's not bounded.

Comment: We haven't learnt limits yet...